# NSLayoutAnchorが上手くいかない

Tags: swift

以下のコードのようにUIScrollView上にボタンを配置しています。
scrollViewのtopAnchorをstatusBar(20px)とnavigationBar(44px)に被らないようにconstant: 64と設定しています。次にNameButtonのtopAnchorをscrollViewのtopAnchorと同じ位置に来るように設定したつもりなのですが、画像のように空白が空いてしまいます。この空白はprintで出力した結果64px空いているようです。scrollViewのNSLayoutAnchorの設定の仕方や考え方が間違っているのか、原因がわかりません。解決方法や原因を教えていただけると助かります。

```
    var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        return sv
    }()
    var nameButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .System)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 120/255, green: 220/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1)
        button.setTitle("Name", forState: .Normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let image = UIImage(named: "back")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleBack))

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        setupScrollView()
    }
    func setupScrollView(){

        scrollView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.widthAnchor).active = true
        scrollView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor).active = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor,constant: 64).active = true
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor).active = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.trailingAnchor).active = true


        scrollView.addSubview(nameButton)
        nameButton.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.leadingAnchor,constant: 20).active = true
        nameButton.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.topAnchor).active = true
        nameButton.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(scrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1/4).active = true
        nameButton.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(36).active = true
    }
```

実行した結果を画像で貼っておきます。
[image: 実行結果]

本当はこのような結果になって欲しいです。
[image: 理想の実行結果]

Storyboardは使っていないため、Storyboardを利用しない解決法など教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UINavigationController` から表示していると想定しますが、この `UIScrollView` には 64pt の `contentInset` （余白）が自動的に付与されます。

`UIViewController` の `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` プロパティを `false` にすればこの挙動はなくなります。

Comment: 自動的に付与されるから余白ができるんですね。納得しました！

 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
これをviewDidLoadに追加したところ上手くいきました！
ありがとうございます。
scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
だと最初は思ったのですが、selfで良かったんでしょうか？

Comment: @SatoshiNatsuyama 失礼しました、`UIViewController`のプロパティでした（修正しました）。iOS6以前には原点の位置が違ったので、それを吸収するためにこのような仕様があります。

Comment: Swiftを始めたばかりで分からないことだらけなので教えて頂けて本当に感謝してます！修正ありがとうございます。今後もよろしくお願いいたします。